# Using Mapbox Boundaries v4 in Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox-studio

I want to highlight a border below the country level in MapBox Studio.
Therefore, I want to use the "Mapbox Boundaries v4" dataset, but Mapbox Studio can not find it.
How can I still use the "Mapbox Boundaries v4" in Mapbox Studio?

[image]